# Big Query : Using case command for the "Dates" using the between function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using the following code to create a new column in my database that includes the seasons.

```
SELECT date, 
CASE 
WHEN date between DATE('2020-01-1') AND DATE('2020-03-20') THEN 'Winter'
WHEN date between DATE('2020-03-21') AND DATE('2020-06-21') THEN 'Spring'
WHEN date between DATE('2020-06-22') AND DATE('2020-08-23') THEN 'Summer'
WHEN date between DATE('2020-08-24') AND DATE('2020-12-21') THEN 'Fall'
END as season
FROM t
```

WHEN I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
No matching signature for operator CASE for argument types: DATE, BOOL, STRING, BOOL, STRING, BOOL, STRING, BOOL, STRING, NULL at [2:7]
```

I don't understand what the problem is. Could you help? thanks

Comment: You are missing single quotes around the second date constant.  You also don't assign a season between the winter solstice and the end of the year.  You might call that "bacchanalia" as did the ancient Romans.

Comment: Thank you but I my original sql, I do actually have the quotes around the second date. I wrote the sql code here and I forgot to add them. Do you think that something else is causing this issue/? @GordonLinoff

Comment: you should double check if the code you presenting here is actually the same code that gives you that error. so far it looks like they are not the same! btw, how about comma before CASE statement?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I actually tried that. I just added the comma and the "date" after case, but getting the same error.

Comment: adding comma was not suggestion for fixing your problem! rather was ask for presenting at least syntax-wise correct query. As of error - reaad my above comments again!

Comment: Would you prefer to ask a different question? For example "How to get the season for any date?"

Answer (score 1):

Mikhail has pointed out that you might have different query in your own workspace.

You can see query below work fine:

```
with t AS (select DATE '2020-1-1' date)
SELECT date, 
CASE 
WHEN date between DATE('2020-01-1') AND DATE('2020-03-20') THEN 'Winter'
WHEN date between DATE('2020-03-21') AND DATE('2020-06-21') THEN 'Spring'
WHEN date between DATE('2020-06-22') AND DATE('2020-08-23') THEN 'Summer'
WHEN date between DATE('2020-08-24') AND DATE('2020-12-21') THEN 'Fall'
END as season
FROM t
```